# click a whole <TD> to go to a link, with parameters and rel tag

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

I ran into a problem.

I know how to make the user click on a whole `<TD>`.

But now, my `<a href='#'>link</a>` has also a `rel` tag, that triggers a plugin (Shadowbox) that opens the link up in a nice popup window, above the whole page that I have.

So how to make the whole TD clickable to go to a link, that's inside it that looks like

```
<td>
<a rel='shadowbox;height=275;width=470' href='send_news_as_mail.php'>send as mail </a>
<td>
```

**UPDATE**

```
.td_clickable
{
display: inline-block; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

this code below is assigne as the class of < a href > ..and you can click on the whole TD.

I just have a little problem now with the vertical-align, the text of the link is set to top, and the vertical-align function does not do the trick.

**FINALLY A WORKING VERSION**

```
.td_clickable
{
display: inline-block; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 45px; 
}


<td>
<a class='td_clickable' rel='shadowbox;height=275;width=470' href='send_news_as_mail.php'>send as mail </a>
<td>
```

Assign this above as a class to your < A HREF > and will expand through the whole TD and you can click anywhere on the TD to access your link.

Also don't forget to do onMouseOver a this.style.cursor="pointer" so it looks nice :)

thanks all for your help!
really appreciate it

Comment: Forget "clicking on the TD element" and think about making the link inside of the `td` element have `display: block` so that it fills the entire `td` element. Of course, if your `td` has padding and stuff, then the padded areas won't be clickable.

Comment: i tried creating the event onClick on a < DIV > inside the < TD >, that holds the < a href >, but I'm stuck on how to open up the Shadowbox plugin. I know it works with rel tag inside an A, but how to do the Javascript for that with onClick, on a surrounding < DIV > ?

Comment: or you were reffering of making the < a href > itself, with display:block ? never tried it :))

Comment: I think your issue is with how you're using shadowbox. Could you post a jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i managed to get the <A> working, making it as big as the whole TD...i'll update the code in my question

Comment: The new question is completely different from the original and should be handled separately. Look at setting line-height or padding on the anchor to fix that.

Comment: You could just assign the css rule: `cursor: pointer` to the link or cell, instead of using javascript for that.